# 360 videos on IE

Tags: html, html5-video, aframe, 360-degrees

I have been trying to explore the possibility of playing 360 degrees videos on Internet Explorer. I am using A-Frame/angular to render all my videos on other browsers and they work well except on IE they play flat.

I recently bumped into Youtube 360 videos on IE11 and was wondering how they achieve that feat. I checked some other websites like Facebook on IE and they play flat.

Is it possible to play 360 videos on IE ? How is youtube doing it? Any ideas would really help me in my research further.

Comment: A-Frame supports Microsoft Edge, but not IE11. More information [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2758).

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame supports VR for any browser that implements the WebVR specification. The list of supported browsers can be found here in the A-Frame docs, Microsoft Edge is listed, IE is not: https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/vr-headsets-and-webvr-browsers.html